# Cómo traducir "shadow" como verbo?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

A veces es frecuente escuchar el término "to shadow" para referirse a alguien que sigue a una persona de mayor experiencia para aprender a base de ver su rutina diaria. A veces es incluso referido como "job shadow" o "work shadowing" (ver [referencia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shadow)).

> Our new intern is going to *shadow* the scrum master today to learn how our different teams apply scrum at the office
>
> As a new resident I was able to *shadow* Dr. Whatever on the operating room

"Shadow" tiene aquí las connotaciones de seguir a alguien, ver lo que hacen y aprender de ellos. Se podría traducir en este contexto como `seguir` o `hacer (de) sombra`.

Sin embargo alguien también puede *shadow* otra persona sin seguirla físicamente. Por ejemplo, si pongo a un becario o a un programador junior a ver cómo un desarrollador más experimentado escribe código o se maneja por la aplicación (con lo que quiero resaltar que no están haciendo *pair programming* sino que uno hace y explica y el otro ve y aprende)los términos `seguir` y `hacer (de) sombra` ya no aplican tan bien.

Se le ocurre a alguien una mejor traducción para esta acepción de `shadow` como verbo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este es un buen ejemplo de la complejidad y precisión del español para acciones subjetivas.

To shadow tiene varios usos en inglés, pero en español existe un verbo para cada caso aplicable a to shadow.

Lo más general a "to shadow" sería [**seguir**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XT8l8aE)

> Del lat. vulg. **sequīre*, y este del lat. *sequi* 'seguir', con la
> t. de *ire* 'ir'. Conjug. c. pedir.
>
> **7. tr. Observar atentamente el curso de un negocio o los movimientos de alguien o algo.**
>
> **11. tr. Imitar o hacer algo por el ejemplo que alguien ha dado de ello.**
>
> **14. prnl. Dicho de una cosa: Suceder a otra por orden, turno o número, o ser continuación de ella.**

Por ejemplo, si nos referimos a lo primero en una relación de jerarquía tácita, el verbo [**secundar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XQFzn71) se ajusta más:

> Del lat. *secundāre*.
>
> **1. tr. Apoyar, cooperar con alguien ayudándole en la realización de sus propósitos.**

Answer (score 4):

Una buena opción -- que de hecho se utiliza, por ejemplo, en el ámbito hospitalario, donde los residentes, a pesar de estar matriculados, cuentan con la tulela o el padrinazgo de un profesional más experimentado -- es "tener como referente a X" o "contar con X como referente".

Traducciones posibles de las oraciones en cuestión serían:

- Hoy nuestro nuevo becario tendrá como referente al experto en resolución de problemas (*any other better translation for* "scrum master" *will be most welcome*) a fin de aprender cómo nuestros distintos equipos aplican esa técnica en la oficina.
- Como nuevo residente, pude contar con Dr. X como referente en el quirófano.

Una oración como : " *I'm shadowing X (in a certain task)* " se traduciría como "X es mi referente (en tal área/tarea)".

"*Job shadow*" y "*work shadowing*" podrían traducirse como "trabajar/trabajo  con un referente".

Answer (score 3):

Es una cuestión difícil, porque en mi opinión no existe un verbo específico que cubra ese significado, así que podría ser mejor explicarlo en más detalle. Quizá se podría decir que "el becario está bajo la tutela de un superior" o que está "tomando a un superior como modelo", en caso de que no lo siga físicamente. Si no, la opción de "ser su sombra" me parece correcta.

Comment: "ser la sombra de alguien" no me parece la mejor opción en este contexto. Generalmente he visto u oído esa expresión como sinónima de "pisarle los talones a alguien" o "seguir a alguien a sol y a sombra", muchas veces con una connotación negativa, como indicando que el "líder" se siente perseguido por su seguidor. Si digo de alguien: "Es mi sombra", muy probablemente quiera significar: "No hay lugar donde (mi seguidor) me deje ir o estar solo".

Comment: El estar bajo la supervisión de alguien y el aprender de esa persona a base de verle realizar su trabajo diario son dos cosas distintas. "Pisarle a alguien los talones" es, en el sentido figurado, estar cerca del logro que la persona tiene (el equipo X le pisa los talones al equipo Y en la liga) pero no tiene las connotaciones que "job shadow" tiene.

Answer (score -1):

El verbo **opacar** seria una buena eleccion a mi criterio.

Comment: That does not seem quite right to me as to shadow means to follow around like a shadow whereas _opacar_ is more like to cast into the shadows.

Comment: de acuerdo con @mdewey. Opcacar, hacer sombra o eclipsar tienen unas connotaciones distintas, con el sentido de la otra persona deja de tener tanta notoriedad debido a que tú (o quien sea) adquiere más notoriedad.