# ¿Existe traducción en español para "Scrum Master"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

En el marco del desarrollo de software existe un término que siempre he escuchado como "Scrum Master". En la entrada en Wikipedia se puede encontrar una definición de [Scrum Master](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)#Scrum_master):

> Scrum is facilitated by a scrum master, who is accountable for removing impediments to the ability of the team to deliver the product goals and deliverables. The scrum master is not a traditional team lead or project manager but acts as a buffer between the team and any distracting influences.

En la [versión en español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(desarrollo_de_software)) de dicha página se encuentra una propuesta de traducción de dicha palabra, que sería *Facilitador*:

> ScrumMaster (o Facilitador)
>   El Scrum es facilitado por un ScrumMaster, cuyo trabajo primario es eliminar los obstáculos que impiden que el equipo alcance el objetivo del sprint.

En una respuesta de [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19778/c%C3%B3mo-traducir-shadow-como-verbo/19786#19786) se menciona e*xperto en resolución de problemas*.

¿Es alguna de estas dos propuestas (*facilitador* o *experto en resolución de problemas*) un traducción adecuada? ¿Es preferible usar la versión en inglés?

Comment: ¡Buena pregunta! Yo nunca he oído nada que no sea _scrum master_ y así aparece en todos los libros y recursos que he leído al respecto. Pero nunca se sabe, tal vez esté emergiendo algún término castizo :)

Comment: @walen no, por favor, puedes responder tú, ya que yo siempre he usado el término en inglés. En todo caso "facilitador" no está mal. También he oído "líder servil".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Si quieres usar la traducción oficial

La traducción oficial de Scrum Master es... **Scrum Master**.

Si consultamos la [guía oficial en español de Scrum [PDF]](http://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v2016/2016-Scrum-Guide-Spanish.pdf#zoom=100), podemos ver que la mayoría de los términos están traducidos: el *Product Owner* es el Propietario del Producto, el *Daily Scrum* es el Scrum Diario... pero el Scrum Master es el Scrum Master, fin.

Así es como lo llama, por ejemplo, [en su web](http://www.javiergarzas.com//?s=scrum%20master) Javier Garzás, una de las personalidades más relevantes de la comunidad Scrum española (según tengo entendido).

#### Si eres un purista del lenguaje

La única traducción formalmente correcta e inequívoca sería "**maestro (de) Scrum**": *master* se traduce a maestro, y Scrum es el nombre de la metodología, no hay que traducirlo. Esta traducción tiene la ventaja de que mantiene el término Scrum, así que todo el mundo sabe de lo que hablas.

Pero casi todo el mundo te mirará raro, porque casi nadie lo dice así; sólo los [libros](https://books.google.es/books?id=ETuXBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT13&lpg=PT13&dq=maestro%20scrum&source=bl&ots=1nLrgZbzlZ&sig=kIVQ56K536wYinWc-q2-XTfi1A0&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD59Kf3sjWAhWLORQKHQYCBHsQ6AEISzAI#v=onepage&q=maestro%20scrum&f=false) y [webs](http://maniqui.ru/las-pequeas-empresas-y-carreras/el-funcionamiento-de-su-negocio/administracin/46581-el-scrum-master-gil-y-obstculos-que-identifican.html) mal traducidos.

Otras alternativas algo menos grotescas serían: "líder Scrum", "experto Scrum", "gestor Scrum".

#### Si quieres usar un término en español sin que te miren raro

Dentro de la propia jerga que se ha desarrollado en español relacionada con el mundo Scrum, es común llamar al Scrum Master "**facilitador**", pues su función es la de facilitar el trabajo al equipo eliminando cualquier factor que les impida ser productivos.

Así es como lo llama por ejemplo [en su web](https://proyectosagiles.org/facilitador-scrum-master/) Xavier Albaladejo, otro veterano del gremio. Aunque también tiene muchas entradas en las que usa directamente Scrum Master.

---

**Mi recomendación**: no lo traduzcas, usa Scrum Master.